# Why am I getting the following error in my Xcode project: No such module 'SwiftyJSON'?

Tags: ios, xcode, swifty-json

I followed the instructions in the github project which are pretty straightforward, I can't figure out why it won't work:

**Instructions**

[image: Instructions]

**My Xcode Project Navigator**

[image: Project Navigator]

**My Swift file**

[image: Error]

Comment: Did you set the target membership correctly?

Comment: What is the target membership?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're following 1. you must not import the file, just use it.

Comment: Ahh this is the answer, I wish they would add that to the documentation.